# C Multiple Indirection

Tags: c, pointers, multiple-indirection

I am currently watching course about pointers in C and I have a question about multiple indirection. I understood what multiple indirection is and that is ok, but I ran on piece of code and I tried to do the same thing on a little different way and it is not working, and I wounder why?
My question is about pointer casting on line 32, why this doesn't work when I cast it like: `printf("Value pointed to by gp is:%s\n",(char *)gp);`
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int data[3];
char *words[3];

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        void *gp;

        char *word = "rijec";
        printf("%s\n",word);

        for(int i = 0; i < 3;i++)
        {
                data[i] = i;
        }
        words[0] = "zero";
        words[1] = "one";
        words[2] = "two";

        gp = data;
        printf("\nAddress of array data is:%p\n",gp);
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
                printf("Value pointed to by gp is %d\n",*(int *)gp);
                gp = (int*)gp+1;
        }
        gp=words;
        printf("\nAddress of array of strings words is:%p\n",gp);
        for(int i = 0;i < 3; i++)
        {
                printf("Value pointed to by gp is:%s\n",*(char **)gp);
                gp  = (char **)gp+1;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't use `(char *)gp` there, because `gp` points to the address where it expects pointers to strings, not the strings themselves. So you need to dereference the pointer first.

Comment: ALSO: I think you probably meant `gp = (int*)gp+i;` and `gp  = (char **)gp+i;`, *NOT" "gp+1".  Because the constant "1" never changes in the loop :(

Comment: "it is not working" ok... so what is going work?

Comment: ohh... the code in the text differs from the code block. Nice trick .... or something :-(

Answer (score 0):

On line 32 `gp` contains the address where the array `words` is stored (because the array words decays to pointer during the assignment). The array `words` consists of 3 pointers. When you cast this to `char *` you tell the compiler to treat this array as if each of its elements is a `char` and not a pointer. You need to dereference the pointer to get the actual string.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
gp=words;
```

`words` is converted to a pointer to the first element of the array. The first element of the array is a `char*`. Consequently, `words` is converted to a `char**`.
So `gp` will hold a pointer of type `char**`

That's why this:

```
printf("Value pointed to by gp is:%s\n",(char *)gp);
                                        ^^^^^^^^
                                        wrong cast
```

is **wrong**

and this:

```
printf("Value pointed to by gp is:%s\n",*(char **)gp);
                                        ^ ^^^^^^^^
                                        |  correct cast
                                        |
                                        correct dereferencing
```

is **correct**